# Cómo leer o recorrer los nodos de un XML que se recibe por curl y no lo hace. En PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

este es l planteamiento:
Recibo una respuesta XML desde un curl en PHP, pretendo obtener ciertos nodos. 
Hago 2 pruebas.
Prueba 1: Toma la respuesta de curl y trato de recorrer ciertos nodos, no lo hace. O, es como sino hiciese el "simplexml_load_string"
Prueba 2: He colocado en una variable ($xmlstr) lo que se mostró en pantalla del resultado del curl. Hago el "simplexml_load_strng" y todo funciona perfectamente.
¿Qúe hago mal en "Prueba 1", por qué no funciona?
Este es un trozo del código que interesa:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Prueba 1 ************* prueba 1 *************
    echo "<br>"." *** Prueba 1 *** "."<br>";
    $xmlstr=$response;
    print_r($xmlstr);
    $nodos = simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode($xmlstr));
    echo "Print de nodos "."<br>";
    print_r($nodos);
    echo "<br>"." Los nodos del simplexml_load_string ";
    echo "<br>"." nodo: ".$nodos."<br>";
    echo "Estado 1: ".$nodos->Respuestas->DatosIdiomas->DatosEnvios->Datos[1]->Estado;
    echo "<br>";

    echo "<br>";
    foreach($nodos->Respuestas->DatosIdiomas->DatosEnvios->Datos as $item)
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo (string)$item->Estado;
        echo (string)$item->Fecha;
    }
//Fin prueba 2 
//Prueba 2 *************** prueba 2
    echo "<br>"." **** Prueba 2 ***"."<br>";
    $xmlstr='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?><ConsultaXMLout xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Respuestas><DatosIdiomas><DatosEnvios><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="1" web_id="Sin web_id"><Estado>Pre registro</Estado><Fecha>29/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="2"><Estado>Admitido</Estado><Fecha>29/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="3"><Estado>Intento de entrega</Estado><Fecha>30/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="4"><Estado>Intento de entrega</Estado><Fecha>30/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="5"><Estado>Intento de entrega</Estado><Fecha>30/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="6"><Estado>Intento de entrega</Estado><Fecha>30/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="7"><Estado>Entregado.</Estado><Fecha>30/05/2019</Fecha></Datos></DatosEnvios></DatosIdiomas></Respuestas></ConsultaXMLout>';
    $nodos = simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode($xmlstr));
    echo "Print de nodos "."<br>";
    print_r($nodos);
    echo "<br>"." Los nodos del simplexml_load_string ";
    echo "<br>"." nodo: ".$nodos."<br>";
    echo "Estado 1: ".$nodos->Respuestas->DatosIdiomas->DatosEnvios->Datos[1]->Estado;
    echo "<br>";

    echo "<br>";
    foreach($nodos->Respuestas->DatosIdiomas->DatosEnvios->Datos as $item)
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo (string)$item->Estado;
        echo (string)$item->Fecha;
    }
//Fin prueba 2
```

***Quiero contar cuantos nodos son, en este caso de los nodos: "Estado" y "Fecha".***

**La respuesta que estoy recibiendo del curl es esta:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?><ConsultaXMLout xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Respuestas><DatosIdiomas><DatosEnvios><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="1" web_id="Sin web_id"><Estado>Pre registro</Estado><Fecha>29/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="2"><Estado>Admitido</Estado><Fecha>29/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="3"><Estado>Intento de entrega</Estado><Fecha>30/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="4"><Estado>Intento de entrega</Estado><Fecha>30/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="5"><Estado>Intento de entrega</Estado><Fecha>30/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="6"><Estado>Intento de entrega</Estado><Fecha>30/05/2019</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ5KF90200060650103203Q" Evento="7"><Estado>Entregado.</Estado><Fecha>30/05/2019</Fecha></Datos></DatosEnvios></DatosIdiomas></Respuestas></ConsultaXMLout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te paso a comentar cómo obtener y leer correctamente el XML con `curl` aunque hay otras opciones más actuales que podrías evaluar ([Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/), por ejemplo)

No sé cómo tienes la inicialización de la variable $ch pero te voy a poner cómo lo tengo yo:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/text.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

1. Primero inicializamos $ch con el enlace al archivo que quieres descargar
2. Le indicamos a curl que queremos que nos devuelva el contenido del enlace en la respuesta
3. Llamamos y obtenemos la respuesta
4. Cerramos curl para liberar recursos

Una vez recibida la respuesta, ya puedes leerla como XML mediante las funciones que has definido:

```
$dataXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
echo $dataXml->Respuestas->DatosIdiomas->DatosEnvios->Datos->count();
```

Comment: Saludos Javi, el $ch recibe una respuesta SOAP. Esa respuesta "cruda" es la que muestro aquí como: "La respuesta que estoy recibiendo del curl es esta:". Es decir, no estoy leyendo un archivo XML "directo" ($ch = curl_init('http://localhost/text.xml'); )  Estoy usando simplexml_load_string($response); sobre una variable ($response) que tiene como valor la respuesta. Gracias Javi Mollá.

Comment: Me da que ahora obtienes el xml y algo más y por eso no lo trata bien ¿Has probado con la instrucción `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` antes de obtener la respuesta?

Comment: Si Javi, utilizo curl_setopt...

Comment: simplexml_load_string() por alguna razón no está convirtiendo la respuesta del curl a un objeto. Allí radica todo el problema, pero, no sé que hacer.